# Custom Blazor Server Component Not Invoking the OnClick Function

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, blazor-component

I have created a layout component in the same directory as with the MainLayout component. The CustomLayout `@inherits LayoutComponentBase` and has `@Body` which gets the content to be rendered inside the layout.

As obviously expected, the layout component has its own css files and UI display is fine. I am only having a problem with the `@onclick function`. It cannot be invoked. Is there a way to trigger the function on button click?

The reason I want to do this is that I am creating a navigation bar which will have to show/hide a dropdown. I hope I can get some ideas on this. Appreciated.

I am calling a server function this way:  `@onclick="SomeFuction"` or  `@onclick="SomeFuction" or @onclick="@(() => SomeFuction())"`

**LayoutComponent:**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@Body
```

**Home page referencing a custom layout:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Layout(typeof(CustomLayoutComponent))]
```

`[AllowAnonymous]` is just for allowing anonymous access.

I am using *Blazor Server* and `.NET 6`

**Additional Information:**
*I have put all the code in one page so that it becomes easier to read and understand.*

**Here is the LayoutComponent razor component:**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="navbar" id="custom-navbar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>Service</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleProductsUI">Products</button>
    </div>  </div>

<!--Component to show Products UI Component. Scoped css for styling--> 

<ProductsComponent TValue="string" UIState="@ProductsUIState"></ProductsComponent>


 @code{
    // state of the Products submenu Component
    string ProductsUIState { get; set; }

    // a control function for toggling the Products UI
    // this function somehow is not invoked.
    void ToggleProductsUI()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProductsUIState))
        {
            ProductsUIState = "show-ui";
            return;
        }
        ProductsUIState = string.Empty;
    }   
}
```

**Here is the ProductsUI component code (I have removed the unnecessary event to avoid confusion. The component can be fully controlled by the parent):**

```
public partial class ProductsComponent<TValue> { 
    [Parameter]
    public string? UIState { get; set; } }
```

**Blazor pages that will use the custom layout component will point to it like this:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Layout(typeof(CustomLayoutComponent))]
public partial class Index
{
}
```

*This is working fine. The issue is in the CustomLayoutComponent when trying to invoke the `ToggleProductsUI()` function*

Comment: The click functions syntax is fine, could you please share complete code, will be helpful to find probable cause of issue

Comment: I have added the information to help understand my situation. Appreciated

Comment: No repro. The code shows you have been editing this before posting and you probaly removed the real cause that way. Use File|NewProject and create a [mre].

Comment: @Henk Holterman
When I create a new project, the custom component is invoking correctly. Let me now verify where I am making an error. If I fail to solve this on my own I will post the entire code. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally inluded a `<body>` element in the layout and as such, the  `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` was not being run hence the click event was not being invoked. I removed the `<body>` element. I was misled by the default `body{}` style in the underlining scopped css. Resolved.